# Question got closed for being unclear, but I'm not sure why

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I noticed that this question was being closed for being unclear:

[Difference between registry.byId and dom.byId in dojo? What is the advantage of using registry.byId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376417/difference-between-registry-byid-and-dom-byid-in-dojo-what-is-the-advantage-of)

Could someone explain me why this question was being closed. I agree that it was poorly formatted due to:

- Code was not well formatted
- It was a code-only question because the question itself only appears in the title

However, I'm confused why this has been closed as being unclear, given the following reasons:

- The question has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376585/1915448) (meaning that it is clear to someone).
- It's a common mistake in the Dojo world to confuse both modules mentioned in the question, this question can be answered by most people who are familiar with Dojo though.

So, I'm assuming the question got closed due to it's quality and thus I improved the formatting of the code and mentioned the question in the post itself in stead of only using the title.

I also commented on the question like mentioned in  [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) and nominated the question for reopening. However, nothing seems to happen. So I'm thinking of any other reasons why this question was closed and/or how it could be improved but I'm not finding any other things to improve it, so I'm asking the community how to do it.

Right now I'm helping the user by using comments, but this doesn't seem to be appropriate either.

Comment: It **is** unclear - what's the code got to do with the question above it (which is overly broad, but still)?.

Comment: As for your argument that "it got an answer therefore it is clear". Um. No. Someone **guessing** they know what the question is about, doesn't mean the question is clear.

Comment: @Oded the question asks for the difference between two things and the code demonstrates the usage of both of them. -- Dimitri: The only thing that could be considered unclear about your question is that you haven't included the output/content of that `innerHTML`.

Comment: Additionally, none of the people who closed have points in [tag:dojo]. The question is likely perfectly clear to someone who *knows* dojo. Voted to reopen. (I mistakenly thought you were the OP in my previous comment)

Comment: @Oded The code is demonstrating the usage of both modules. You can see that it prints 4 things, these "4 things" are the carthesian product of the modules (registry.byId and dom.byId) and the things it can be used on (widgets and DOM nodes). 2 of them will yield a result and 2 of them won't. But this information could indeed be added to the question (though it's very clear to someone who has worked with Dojo).

Comment: It's unclear because your brains unclear as you don't know what is unclear. Overall it is unclear.

Comment: @Oded Ok, someone could indeed be guessing. But the answer is indeed answering the question + the question is also clear to me and I would be responding in a similar way... . The only difference between the other answerer + me and the 5 who closed the question is that we have experience in Dojo while the other 5 (as @Stijn) mentioned do not have that experience.

Comment: @DimitriM - that's a fair point and a general problem we have (people without enough knowledge about a subject closing a valid question).

Comment: @Oded Ok, maybe it should been made easier for people with high reputation in a specific tag to reopen questions related to it? Or will that give other problems? I have no idea how the nominating process works. Anyways, I made another edit to the question to explain what the code does (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23376417/revisions) and I hope it has been made more clear now.

Comment: @DimitriM - we already give that privilege to high rep users. And your edit may very well have put the question in the reopen queue (it currently has 4 reopen votes, so probably getting open soon).